# Inequality for product of integrals

Tags: integration, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Consider two real-valued functions $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is this relation true:

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)f(x)dx\leq \sup_x f(x)\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)dx
$$

? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you restate that inequality with absolute values then it is true. Consider the Riemann integral in terms of the limit of a series. Let $M=sup\{f(x):x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $a<b$ be arbitrary points on the real line. Define $x_i=a+i/n$. Then:

$$\int_{a}^{b}|g(x)|f(x)dx=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i^*)|g(x_i^*)|[x_i-x_{i-1}]$$

$$\leq\lim_{n \to \infty} M\sum_{i=1}^n|g(x_i^*)|[x_i-x_{i-1}]$$

$$=M\int_{a}^{b}|g(x)|dx$$

As this is true for an arbitrary interval $[a,b]$ it is true for the whole Real line.

Comment: Do we need $M=sup\{|f(x)|: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$?

Comment: No because as you we're taking the absolute value of M anyway so it wouldn't make a difference. In fact we can get a stronger result just taking the absolute value of g. Let me edit quickly.

Comment: The result still holds for negative values of $f$

Comment: And also replacing $M$ with $sup\{|f(x)|: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ or $sup\{|f(x)|: x \in [a,b]\}$, right?

Comment: No there's no need for that. $M$ as I defined it can be negative and the result still follows. If $f$ is negative then $M$ is the biggest value (smallest "negative value") that $f$ takes. And a smaller negative number multiplied by a positive ($|g(x)|$) is always greater than a bigger negative number. I.e $(-10*2)<(-5*2)$. Obviously this property holds when summed over

Answer (score 1):

Let $f = \mathbb{1}_{[1,2]}$  and $g = - \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$ .

Then $f(x)g(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, so the LHS is $0$, whereas the RHS is $1 \cdot (-1) = -1$.

However, if $g(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, and if $f$ is bounded from above, then the inequality holds.